Is there easy way to find a string or sequence of characters in all Oracle Database objects Source code
How can find the a string like 'FD%', 'FD', 'FD  with regardless of case sensitivity in oracle database objects source code like package spec, package body , table, view, Materialized view , procedure, function, trigger and etc
I tried the following but did not come all my needs
     SELECT  distinct name, type
     FROM dba_source
        WHERE instr (UPPER(text), UPPER(:search_text)) >0
        --and owner like 'APPS'
      and type in ('TRIGGER', 'PACKAGE BODY', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION') 
     --and NAME like 'EKG%'

